# jQuery remote validation not working in ASP.net project

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate

I can't seem to figure out how to trigger remote validation in my form.  What I eventually need to do is verify that a value does not exist in our MySQL database before the user clicks on Submit so they'll know there's a problem immediately.  Currently, I'm not even trying to talk to the database, the web method simply returns `false.ToString();`

The form validation is working just fine, but the remote validation never triggers my breakpoint in the code behind and I don't know what I'm missing.  The following code snippets have been pared down from the actual code (there are half a dozen more required items on the form, but I'm not showing them or the JS associated with validating them), but it's the same code I'm using for proof of concept.  The JSON string I'm sending is forced in the AJAX call, but once I get it working it'll be using the actual user input that'll be JSON.stringify-ed.

If it's useful I can post a fiddle so you can see the entirety of the code (obviously the AJAX won't work).

HTML / ASP.NET:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="create._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PCBClient</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <link href="Styles/codiqa.ext.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/css/screen.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/codiqa.ext.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/pcbclient.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" data-control-title="Create" id="pageCreate" class="events">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
             <h2>
          Create
      </h2>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <form id="formEvent_create" action="">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="radiobuttons">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
                        <legend>Type of PCBID Entry:</legend>
                        <input id="radio1" name="radio_pcbids" value="rdo_pcbid_single" type="radio">
                        <label for="radio1">Single PCBID</label>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="textinput" class="pcbid_selections" tabindex="1">
                    <label for="pcbid_single">Single PCBID *</label>
                    <input name="pcbid_single" id="pcbid_single" class="create_group" placeholder="52759" value="" type="text" data-mini="true">
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="textinput" class="eventType" style="display: none;">
                    <label for="eventType_create"></label>
                    <input name="eventType_create" id="eventType_create" placeholder="" value="Creation" type="hidden">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" data-inline="true" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" value="Back" class="back">
                <input type="submit" data-inline="true" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="left" value="Submit">
                <input type="submit" data-inline="true" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="left" value="Clear">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="Result">Create</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS (pcbclient.js):

```
$("#formEvent_create").validate({
    submitHandler: function (form, event)
    {
        console.log($(this));
        isFormValid(form, event);
    },
    rules: {
        pcbid_single: {
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            rangelength: [3, 6],
            remote: {
                url: "Default.aspx/pcbidCheck",
                type: "post",
                data: '{"pcbid": 52759}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg)
                {
                    $("Result").text("\nThe PCBID does not exist in the database\nThe query returned: " + msg.d);
                }
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        pcbid_single: "Please enter a valid PCBID with 3-6 digits."
    }
});
```

Code behind (Default.aspx.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace create
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public static string pcbidCheck(string pcbid)
        {
            return false.ToString();
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**  I have been unable to find a working example of this anywhere on SO or other sources, nor have I been able to figure it out on my own, and none of the support forums out there for jQuery Validation appear to respond to help requests (other than SO), so I've dropped back & punted.  I'm going to do two separate AJAX calls on Submit, one to verify the PCBID (it's a unique integer value in our MySQL db) exists, and upon receiving that call back, either process or not the subsequent event data with another AJAX call depending on the result of the first AJAX call.

If anyone reads this and has an ASP.NET example of remote validation using jQuery validation that works I'd love to see it.  I still very much want to be able to do on-blur remote validation so the user knows immediately whether there's a problem with the PCBID integer value they've entered.  However, at some point I have to move forward with the project and I spent days trying to figure this out.

Comment: It really seems like you have way too many `remote` options.  Since you're just testing this out, try `remote: "Default.aspx/pcbidCheck"` for starters.

Comment: You don't need an `isFormValid` function within the `submitHandler`, because by definition, the `submitHandler` can ONLY fire when the form is already valid.

Comment: @Sparky, it's a small subroutine (perhaps confusingly named) that runs to build a JS object after validation succeeds to be sent to the codebehind, but is immaterial in this example (I have a working example of this for the actual submittal that works as expected).

I'll give your suggestion about removing remote options and see what I get.

Comment: Remember, the default method for `remote` is `GET`, so you might just need the `type: "post"` option.

Comment: I changed it to only: `remote { url: "Default.aspx/pcbidCheck, type: "post"}` and nothing seems to have changed.  There are no complaints in the console.  When should the remote validation fire?  As soon as the local validation is satisfied (EG: it accepts 3-6 digits but before I click on Submit?)  Should there be a keyup or blur event it's looking for?

Comment: `remote` will fire like any other rule... by default, on every keyup, on blur, and on click of the submit button.  I'm no ASP expert, but in PHP, you would `echo` `true/false` or a JSON string.  You would not use a `return` for this.

Comment: I think you need to replace that `return` with a `response.write()`.

Comment: I changed the return type of the web method to void (since it's no longer returning anything), and then added `HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("false");`, but nothing has changed.  The front end validation continues to work as expected, but the code behind is never even being hit (or at least not stopping on the breakpoint).  The other project that I have working returns a string from the web method that's just a `bool.ToString();` so I should be able to do something similar (or at least that was my thought going into this). But that one depends on a Submit event handler.

Comment: I use `remote` all the time (with PHP) without any trouble, so I'm not sure how to help you further.

Comment: If you have the `remote` rule, **I can guarantee you that it's trying to access the file at the URL**.  Are you sure the path is correct?   It's relative to the location of the page where the jQuery is used.  Look at the response codes from your console.  Are you getting any 404, etc?

Comment: Thanks for the try, I appreciate it.  I'll keep plugging away, I'm hoping @DaveWard stops by, I'm using his examples to work from.  And no, I'm not getting any 404 (or any other errors) in the console.  The JS file is in a \scripts subdir and the aspx file is in the parent directory.  Since there are no errors in the console, it would seem that that's (probably) not the problem?

Comment: No errors maybe, but you should still see a response code from the server when trying to access that file.

Comment: I'm dropping back & punting.  I'm going to spend the time to work through Dave Ward's example on [Encosia](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) so I can see it work and figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I've been successful with his examples before and I'm reasonably certain I'm just doing something incorrectly.  Thanks again for the effort, I really appreciate it.

Comment: In any case, whenever you figure it out, don't forget to post your solution as an answer.